# Keycloak - How can I change EmailSenderProvider?

Tags: oauth, keycloak

I cannot send e-mails via SMTP using Keycloak on my business laptop. How can I change `EmailSenderProvider` in standalone Keycloak server ?

Answer (score 0):

The `EmailSenderProvider` class is in `keycloak-server-spi-private` module/jar which means it's not supposed to be replaced by a custom implementation. SPIs that you can implement are all in `keycloak-server-spi` module.